# Version 1.0 released 9th of July

Tags: support, api, meta, api-v1

For a lot of us, that would be next Friday.

At some point - most likely after noon PST - version 0.9 of the API will be replaced with the final 1.0 release.

<strike>There are no expected interface changes between now and 1.0.</strike>
There has been [one change](https://stackapps.com/questions/1048/in-the-timeline-the-ability-to-know-what-events-belong-to-what-question) in the 0.9 timeframe.

<strike>This question will be updated once the transition has occurred.</strike>

Version 1.0 of the API is here, officially, as of ~1:30 PM PST.  Enjoy.

Comment: Thankyou very much for the heads up. We shall be prepared!

Comment: Does "no interface changes" mean no new routes, or no changes whatsoever?

Comment: @Dave - no changes outside of bug fixes or performance improvements.

Comment: fantastic!!!! And it only took 1 ssh and a vi to fix StackTop :)

Comment: @Matt: Easy for you to say... you don't have 8 or 10 apps to update!

Comment: @Kevin Goooood job!Greetings from Italy.

Comment: Ah, you obviously don't have a rule that was very dear to me -- nothing goes to production on Fridays :p

Answer (score 11):

Thank you for that.

Answer (score 3):

I assume this means that the contest will end at that time?

...and the winner will be announced?

Comment: You know, it's not all about the contest, it's about creating awesome applications that utilize the API.

Comment: The contest will end sometime after the transition.  One of the clauses is that your [app] has to run against 1.0, which is kind of tricky before 1.0 is out there.  There will be some time for transition, exactly how much is TBD and will be announced either here or (more likely) on the blog.

Comment: @Matt, in the same way that SOFU is not about rep...

Comment: @Farseeker: Ya, you're right :)

Comment: @farseeker for some reason I think that was meant for @code from this post: http://stackapps.com/questions/802/questions-response-missing-fields

Answer (score 1):

Awesome!  And my application is done as well :)  I'm still not sure if I'm going to add any more to it until 1.0 is out.  There are a few things I haven't implemented that are in the API, but I want StackTop to be treated more like a Twitter client, so I'm not too worried about adding features like comments (sure it's kinda a big thing on Stack Apps, but on the other sites I don't see it as a highly used feature) and allowing my users to search for users on Stack Exchange sites

Answer (score 1):

Press this button to add a reminder to your calendar.
[image]

PS: This is the first time I'm sharing a single event, let me know if it works.
PPS: Let me also know if by mistake I shared my entire calender with the web :)