# In the timeline the ability to know what events belong to what question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, api, timeline

Take this example:
http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.9/questions/3165492;3182016/timeline

Would it not make sense to have the question_id as a parameter on each timeline object? It makes the timeline api pretty useless if you pass more than one question id does it not?

I would like to build a monitoring system for questions and batching up requests to the timeline api seemed the most sensible way to achieve this.

Comment: Bah, it says something about the usage `/questions/{id}/timeline` has gotten that this oversight wasn't spotted until the day before 1.0 release....  But its a pretty major one.  [status-planned], will happen today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been done.

`question_id` is now found on every element in the returned set.

[Updated documentation](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.9/questions/1/timeline?help).

Presumably the last change before 1.0.