# Exclude records where field is present (ie., return only open questions)

Tags: support, api, api-v2.2, parameters

How do I *exclude* records based on the presence of a certain field (like the equivalent of SQL's `[fieldname] Is Null`)?

**Example**:

- Results for **Closed** questions include field **`closed_date=1234567890`**.
- Results for **Open** questions do not include this field as a *`Null`* as I would expect.

Is there a parameter I can add to the URL to **exclude questions that *have* the field**?

---

The only information I could find was from the documentation:

> **Absent Fields**
>
> <sub>To save space, the API does not return null values, instead opting to exclude the field altogether in the returned JSON. Fields that are not always guaranteed to be set (closed_date on question objects for example) are indicated in the per-type documentation.  ([**Source**](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/absent-fields))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 questions:

1. "How do I exclude records based on the presence of a certain field?"
   *Answer:* The API will not do this for you; your code must filter out these results.
2. "(How do I ) return only open questions?"
   *Answer:* Use [the /search/advanced route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search).

---

#### Exclude records where field is present:

**The API does not do this** for any field, and seems unlikely to add the capability.  <sup><sub>(See [this somewhat related answer to "API responses are sometimes missing fields"](https://stackapps.com/a/809/7653).}</sub></sup>

Your app/script must loop through the results and exclude the ones you are not interested in.

For example, this query to `/questions`:
          [/2.2/questions?tagged=notifications&site=stackapps](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=notifications&filter=!iCF4LqKg6_AjpCrDN*(A.)&site=stackapps&run=true)

returns:

```js
{ "items": [ {
      "title": "Top Bar for Chat Rooms"
    }, {
      "title": "Get our Stack Exchange inbox as native notification on Chrome"
    ...
    }, {
      "closed_date": 1382175473,
      "title": "Mark notification/inbox item as read"
    }, {
      "title": "Trying to get the Total results count crashes the /notifications path"
    ...
    } ],
  "total": 13
}
```

Your code would loop through that and reject items where `typeof closed_date != "undefined`.

---

#### Return only open questions:

For such "complex" queries, [the `/search/advanced` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search) was added.

There you have two options:

1. You can use the `closed=False` parameter provided:
   [/2.2/search/advanced?closed=False&tagged=notifications&site=stackapps](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&closed=False&tagged=notifications&filter=!iCF4LqKg6_AjpCrDN*(A.)&site=stackapps&run=true)
2. Or you can leverage the `q` parameter -- which mimics much of the functionality of [the website search](https://stackapps.com/help/searching):
   [/2.2/search/advanced?q=closed:no&tagged=notifications&site=stackapps](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=closed%3Ano&tagged=notifications&filter=!iCF4LqKg6_AjpCrDN*(A.)&site=stackapps&run=true)